# Django unit testing - Why can't I just run ./tests.py on myApp?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, unit-testing, pydev

So I'm very familiar with `manage.py test myapp`.  But I can't figure out how to make my `tests.py` work as an stand-alone executable.  You may be wondering why I would want to do this.. Well I'm working (*now*) in Eclipse and I can't seem to figure out how to set up the tool to simply run this command.  Regardless it would be very nice to simply wrap `tests.py` in a simple manner to just run that.

Here is what my `tests.py` looks like.

```
"""
This simply tests myapp
"""
import sys
import logging
from django.test import TestCase

from django.conf import settings
from django.test.utils import get_runner

class ModelTest(TestCase):

    def test_model_test1(self):
        """
        This is test 1
        """
        self.failUnlessEqual(1 + 1, 2)

    def test_model_test2(self):
        """
        This is test 2
        """
        self.failUnlessEqual(1 + 1, 2)

    def test_model_test3(self):
        """
        This is test 3
        """
        self.failUnlessEqual(1 + 1, 2)

def run_tests():
    test_runner = get_runner(settings)
    failures = test_runner([], verbosity=9, interactive=False)
    sys.exit(failures)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Setup Logging
    loglevel = logging.DEBUG
    logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)-8s %(asctime)s %(name)s %(message)s",
                        datefmt='%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', stream=sys.stdout)
    log = logging.getLogger("")
    run_tests()
```

I think the solution is located on this line but I can't seem to figure out what the first argument needs to be in order for it to magically start working..

```
failures = test_runner([], verbosity=9, interactive=False)
```

Thanks for helping!!

**** Updates ****

What I am looking to do (Doh!) is to simply run "myApp" tests.  The problem is that this works (and chmod is not the problem) but it wants to run the entire test suite.  I don't want that. I just want to run the `myApp` test suite.

Thanks again!

Comment: If you could show us something of how it doesn't work, it'd be easier to help.

Comment: What happens now when you run it is that it wants to run the entire suite for "all" apps I just want it to run for this app. Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using an "External Tool Configuration" to run your test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an "External Tool" configuration for your project, such as:

```
Location: ${project_loc}/src/${project_name}/manage.py
Working Directory: ${project_loc}/src/${project_name}/
Arguments: test ${string_prompt}
```

This will run manage.py test <whatever name you type in the string prompt>.

The values above assume that you created a [pydev](http://pydev.org/) project in Eclipse and then housed your Django project in the pydev src directory. It also assumes that you have the project name for pydev be the same name of your Django project. It will use the currently selected project in the package explorer to determine `project_loc` and `project_name`.

Comment: You totally nailed it!!  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

a. this should be the first line at your code file (tests.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

b. run `$ chmod +x tests.py`

Comment: Nope this already is done.  It works from the command line no problem.